# Linked List implementation- Program crashing

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I was developing a generic linked list. Although the compiler doesn't give any error but on running the program, it just crashes. I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong but since I am trying insert method of the list in `main`, the problem is somewhere there itself. Here's the code in **List.h**

```
#include<cstdlib>

enum Error_code
{
    success,
    overflow,
    underflow,
    range_error
};

template<class Node_entry>
struct Node
{
    Node_entry entry;
    Node<Node_entry> *next;

    Node()
    {
        next=NULL;
    }

    Node(Node_entry item, Node<Node_entry> *add_on=NULL)
    {
        entry=item;
        next=add_on;
    }
};

template<class List_entry>
class List
{
  public:
    List()
    {
        count=0;
        head=NULL;
    }

    Error_code insert(int position, const List_entry &x)
    {
        if(position<0 || position>count)
            return range_error;
        Node<List_entry> *previous, *following, *new_node;
        if(position>0) {
            previous=set_position(position-1);
            following=previous->next;
        } else {
            following=head;
        }
        new_node = new Node<List_entry>(x, following);
        if(new_node==NULL)
            return overflow;
        if(position==0)
            head=new_node;
        else
            previous->next=new_node;
        count++;
        return success;
    }

    Error_code remove(int position, List_entry &x)
    {
        if(position<0 || position>count)
            return overflow;
        Node<List_entry> *old_node, *previous;
        if(position==0)
            old_node=head;
        else {
            previous=set_position(position-1);
            old_node=previous->next;
        }
        if(old_node==NULL)
            return underflow;
        if(position==0) {
            head=old_node->next;
            delete old_node;
        } else {
            previous->next=old_node->next;
            delete old_node;
        }
        count--;
        return success;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return count==0;
    }

    ~List()
    {
        Node<List_entry> *temp_node=head->next;
        while(!empty()) {
            delete head;
            head=temp_node;
            temp_node=head->next;
        }
    }

  protected:
    int count;
    Node<List_entry> *head;

    Node<List_entry> *set_position(int position)const
    {
        Node<List_entry> *q=head;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            q=q->next;
        return q;
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include"List.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    List<int> the_list;
    the_list.insert(1, 2);
}
```

P.S I am just into learning the basics for now and not working on large scale design modules and practices. At this point, this only needs to work.

Comment: It's not a good pratice to include "code" into the header file. Just put the prototypes into the header.

Comment: Its a generic implementation. If I make sepearate definition and code file, it gives an error.

Comment: Could you indent your code plz ? It's really not readable at all :(

Comment: @ykatchou: these are template classes, so the code *needs* to be in the header.

Comment: Btw: You insert an element in an empty list to the 2nd position (1st position: 0, 2nd position: 1)

Comment: @ykatchou: As larsmans has said, you must put the full source in a header for the template.

Comment: @philpsy: I get that! But even in writing `the_list.insert(0,1)` the problem persists :-|

Comment: Is there a specific reason for "set_position" being a protected method here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in your `main` function is:

1. Construct list; success.
2. Try to `insert` at position 1, which fails with `range_error` because `position>count`. If you choose to return error codes, you should always check for them.
3. Destroy list. This segfaults because `head` is `NULL` when you try to dereference it with `Node<List_entry> *temp_node=head->next;`

Comment: Inadvertently, I made this list presuming the list is already populated. Can you please help me on how to initialize and populate the list for the first time?

Comment: Put a check for `head == NULL` in the `insert` member and set `head` if true. Also check for `NULL` in other members, including the destructor, as @DeadMG suggests.

Comment: I changed it but the crash problem is still there. Is this correct now? http://pastebin.com/fViVQKRK

Answer (score 4):

You set the head to NULL in the constructor, but don't check for null in any of your functions. In set_position, you blindly try to iterate through head and accompanying nodes without verifying that they actually exist.

Comment: Especially in the destructor, derefencing `head` via `head->next`. That's the position where you get a SEGFAULT.

Comment: @phlipsy: It's UB, since the OP doesn't specify his platform.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to other answers - `set_position` method has a bug, it uses `count` instead of `position`.